# best practice for large (2M~) bundles for Rails 5/6 and Webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

For my rails app, the webpacker-bundled application.js is already too large (~2M) because of jquery, quill, and some other js dependencies. Currently, I am bundling everything into a single js file, which is loaded by every HTML page. As a result, the page loading time is not acceptable.

So I am thinking of a few methods to fix this problem:

1. generate different application.js for different layouts.
2. use webpack externals for jquery, quill, and some other dependencies.

Are these the best options? Any suggests?

Comment: If this is a production environment then you should be precompiling your assets. Nice article to introduce you to webpacker if you need: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/